# Tensorflow save and restore variables are not the same

Tags: tensorflow

It's from Udacity deep learning foundation course. It seems to work for them. But it doesn't work in my computer. Please have a look. Appreciate your helps!

The tensorflow versions from the lecture and my computer are both 1.0.0.

```
import tensorflow as tf

# The file path to save the data
save_file = './model.ckpt'

# Two Tensor Variables: weights and bias
weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([2, 3]))
bias = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3]))

# Class used to save and/or restore Tensor Variables
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Initialize all the Variables
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    # Show the values of weights and bias
    print('Weights:')
    print(sess.run(weights))
    print('Bias:')
    print(sess.run(bias))

    # Save the model
    saver.save(sess, save_file)

# Remove the previous weights and bias
tf.reset_default_graph()

# Two Variables: weights and bias
weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([2, 3]))
bias = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3]))

# Class used to save and/or restore Tensor Variables
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Load the weights and bias
    saver.restore(sess, save_file)

    # Show the values of weights and bias
    print('Weight:')
    print(sess.run(weights))
    print('Bias:')
    print(sess.run(bias))
```

Comment: Your code works for me with an up-to-date TensorFlow. Can you update to the latest TensorFlow release and try again? If it still doesn't work, what goes wrong? Do you get an error or a wrong output?

Answer (score 0):

Insert `tf.reset_default_graph()` after importing tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code in 1.1.0, the results are the same...